# How to display image based dropdown rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I need to implement following type of drop-downs in my application how can i manage in the rails. Please Advice.

[image]

Please advice,
thanks

Comment: This is not a Rails question. More of a HTML/JS/CSS

Comment: I am in search of GEM which does so...

Comment: This is absolutely a front-end HTML/CSS/JS based feature, you are talking about. From what I know - No gems would ever intend do this. You might want to look into some JS-libraries that does so. And Bootstrap is obviously the best.

Answer (score 2):

This has more to do with HTML/CSS/JS, nothing about rails. 
You could simply use [BootStrap-Dropdown-component](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#dropdowns) to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any gem which helps for this if i use such thing i will have to manage the data in the hidden fields. I want to be on safer side.

Comment: @Baran, please go through the Bootstrap link once. There is ZERO complexity in it. You simply have to use the bootstrap.js and the HTML he had provided. 
This is absolutely a front-end HTML/CSS/JS based feature, you are talking about. No gems would do this.

Comment: I have its implementation in JS and CSS. I am in search of any dynamic thing. You know as its a common thing now a days just same as facebook.